# Delphi COM object not showing up in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, delphi, pascal

I am trying to create a COM object in Delphi and use it in a C# WPF project.

I have created a new DLL project in Delphi 10.3, using *File -> New -> Other*, then *Delphi -> Windows -> ActiveX Library*. I have created the following IDL in the GUI editor for my *.ridl file:

```
[
  uuid(E999851C-1E08-4C64-B82A-C3A979F96C2F),
  version(1.0)

]
library DelphiCOMService
{

  importlib("stdole2.tlb");

  interface IDelphiCOMService;


  [
    uuid(50749CD6-4BA7-4200-AB87-67D9590EAA1A),
    version(1.0),
    dual,
    oleautomation
  ]
  interface IDelphiCOMService: IDispatch
  {
    [id(0x000000C9)]
    HRESULT _stdcall EmbedWPFWindow([in] unsigned long Pointer, [in] int Width, [in] int Height);
    [id(0x000000CA)]
    HRESULT _stdcall WindowResized([in] int Width, [in] int Height);
  };

};
```

In Design view, I hit *Refresh Implementation*, *Register Type Library*, and *Save As Type Library File*. It says registration of the ActiveX Server was successful. I hit Build on my project. No errors or issues.

I added the following unit to implement the interface:

```
unit DelphiCOMServiceImplementation;

interface

uses ComObj, DelphiCOMService_TLB, Winapi.ActiveX;

type
  DelphiCOMService = class(TAutoObject, IDelphiCOMService)
  public
    procedure EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
    procedure WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
  end;

implementation

procedure DelphiCOMService.EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

procedure DelphiCOMService.WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

end.
```

I rebuilt my project, no errors so far. I went and hit *Run -> ActiveX Server -> Register*. It was successful.

I would expect it to have a registered the COM object on my system now, or am I wrong? In my WPF C# project, when I try to *Add Reference...*, it does not show up under *COM -> Type Libraries*. Am I missing something?

Comment: Delphi is native, so there might be 32-bit vs 64-bit issues. Try to compile the  delphi lib as 64-bit?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Both the Delphi and WPF solution are 32-bit, so it should be compiled as 32-bit on both sides.

Comment: If you use the IDE's main menu and choose *Component->Import Component->Import ActiveX control*, does your ActiveX show up in the list to import?

Comment: @KenWhite No, it does not. Strange...

Comment: What result + msg do you get if you try to register your dll using Delphi's TRegSvr utility?

Comment: Are you running Delphi as administrator? Because only then it can normally register your activex control.

Comment: @MartynA The output from the result is a copyright notice followed by the following text (ran it elevated, of course): *Call to DllRegisterServer was successful!*

Comment: @R.Hoek Yes, I am

Comment: Also, I've tried *regsvr32 DelphiCOMService.dll*, and it says *DllRegisterServer in DelphiCOMService succeeded*, but I don't see it, either when trying to import a COM object or an Active X control...even from a different Delphi project after activating it. So weird...also this is my first time doing this, never tried creating a Delphi type library before. I hope I am going about it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the COM object's interface in the *.ridl Design editor; I tried adding the same interface as a DispInterface just for kicks, that didn't work, and then, deleting the DispInterface and adding back the original Interface seemed to work (+ Refresh, Register, and Save as TLB). Also, I noticed that leaving a Version of 0.0 for my interface may be the reason why it worked. Originally, I tweaked the Version to 1.0 when I first built it out. If someone could shed some light as to why this could happen, I would also be quite intrigued to know!